# Can I suppress system alerts in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, idle-timer

Is it possible for my app to "take over" when a system alert pops up? My app disables the idle timer, but when a system alert pops up, the alert seems be enabling the timer. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to suppress the alerts? Then the answer is: you can't.

If you're trying to prevent the alerts from messing with your app's disabling of the idle timer, then I believe donkim is on the right trail.

Comment: What about making the alerts resign the first responder status so that my app won't hang. A system alert makes the active app considered to be inactive, believe it or not.

Comment: I don't believe you can get a handle on the alert, so no, you can't make it resign first responder. Your app needs to deal with being made inactive.

Answer (score 3):

Would it be possible for you to hook into one of the methods that gets called when your app goes in and out of the background? Say, one of these?

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive");
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground");
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");
}
```

I bet one of those gets called when that happens. You can probably disable the idle timer when your app gets the focus back.

EDIT: On re-reading the question, it looks like you're looking to suppress the alerts (i.e., not let them happen). Heh, I focused on the latter half of your question.

Comment: Read more details about what's going on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576204/help-with-why-my-app-crashed